# Flutter readonly Textfield set caret to end

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a `TextField` that I set to `readonly`, and it contains a `TextEditingController`. When I set the text on the controller through code, I want the text field to jump all the way to the back.

[image]

```dart
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  controller: _dialogStore.exportFolderPathController,
),
```

The store in this case is part of mobx, which I use instead of stateful widgets. But that doesn't matter for the question here.

I have a rather small text box. So when the text is long I want the text field to scroll all the way to the end. When I set the text on the scroll controller via `exportFolderPathController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: exportFolderPathController.text.length);`, it doesn't want to update, but when I set `readonly` to `false`, it does work.

I have been digging through the code and found hints of `if(readonly)`, for showing the selection handlers.

Eventually I got it to work with a dirty `bool` and a `Future.delayed` solution like so:

```dart
Future<void> setFilePath(String filePath) async {
  _readonly = false;
  exportFolderPathController.text = filePath;
  exportFolderPathController.selection =
      TextSelection.collapsed(offset: exportFolderPathController.text.length);
  // wait for the scroll animation to finish
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  _readonly = true;
}
```

I really don't like the `Future.delayed` here, since it's an assumtion that it will take a while for the animation to finish. What are my alternatives?

I saw that there is also the possibility to add a `ScrollController`, but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest and easiest solution is below

Initialize a scrollController

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Then assign that controller in TextField

```
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  controller: _dialogStore.exportFolderPathController,
  scrollController: _scrollController,
)
```

Last step is to add 2 lines in your `setFilePath()` method

```
Future<void> setFilePath(String filePath) async {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    final scrollOffset = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    _scrollController.jumpTo(scrollOffset);
  });
}
```

call above method in initState.

And you're done. You'll achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice solution! I like how the ScrollController is used here. Thanks!